# Watchkit - How pass multiple values with contextForSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: swift, segue, watchkit, watchos-2

I currently pass a string value from one `WKInterfaceController` to another using `contextForSegueWithIdentifier` like so:

```
override func contextForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String, inTable table: WKInterfaceTable, rowIndex: Int) -> AnyObject? {

    if segueIdentifier == "segueDetails" {
        return self.string1
    }

    // Return data to be accessed in ResultsController
    return nil
}
```

And then on the destination `WKInterfaceController` I do the following:

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    if let val: String = context as? String {
        self.label.setText(val)
    } else {
        self.label.setText("")
    }
    // Configure interface objects here.
}
```

However I want to pass multiple values, using two additional properties with string values called `string2` and `string3`.

How can I pass additional string values to the `WKInterfaceController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift has three collection types: `Array`, `Dictionary`, and `Set`.

**Passing the context as an array of strings:**

```
    ...
    if segueIdentifier == "segueDetails" {
        return [string1, string2, string3]
    }

func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    // Configure interface objects here.
    if let strings = context as? [String] {
        foo.setText(strings[0])
        bar.setText(strings[1])
        baz.setText(strings[2])
    }
}
```

**Passing the context as a dictionary:**

```
    ...
    if segueIdentifier == "segueDetails" {
        return ["foo" : string1, "bar" : string2, "baz" : string3]
    }

func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    // Configure interface objects here.
    if let strings = context as? [String: String] {
        foo.setText(strings["foo"])
        bar.setText(strings["bar"])
        baz.setText(strings["baz"])
    }
}
```

Personally, I prefer using a dictionary, as the array approach would be a bit more fragile if the caller ever changed the order or the number of strings.

Either way, add necessary checks to make your code robust.